# Cloves vs. Nutmeg in Chili Recipe

Tags: substitutions, chili

I have a recipe that calls for a scant amount of cloves. Would nutmeg be a good substitute?

Comment: What other spices are in the recipe?

Comment: Does the recipe call for clove powder (one of the few spices that is more potent than nutmeg!) or whole cloves anyway?

Comment: I would like to remind the people answering that question that "what spices taste good in chili" is not a valid question here. So please don't interpret the question that way, and don't post answers listing other spices for the chili.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, yes. Go easy, you can always add more, but you can't take it away.

I would actually grab nutmeg for chili long before I would consider cloves.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jolenealaska and would also suggest allspice or cinnamon. The warmth of those, and adding cumin, does very well in chili.